# Coffeescript not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript

I have a two date fields on my page (from and to date) that I am using javascript datepicker in. The two fields display the date picker fine in dev, but not on heroku. Here is the coffee script...

```
jQuery ->
  $('#event_starts_at').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  $('#event_ends_at').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

Here is the html displayed...

```
<div class="field">
From Date
<input id="event_starts_at" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" size="30" name="event[starts_at]">
</div>
<div class="field">
To Date
<input id="event_ends_at" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" size="30" name="event[ends_at]">
</div>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Have you tried using http://js2coffee.org to check the syntax is okay?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes syntax is OK. I only a a warning in the console on heroku that is "use of getpreventdefault() is deprecated. use defaultprevented instead" but I don't think that is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Just need to pre-compile assets for the change to take effect on heroku.